# Code explanation about subset in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this particular code for finding the best-rated movies in a year which goes like this:

```
best_movies = []
for year, subset in data.groupby('year'):
    is_best_movie = subset.rating == subset.rating.max()
    best_movies.append([year,subset[is_best_movie].title.values[0], subset.rating.max()])
best_df = pd.DataFrame(best_movies,columns=['year','title','rating'])
best_df.tail()
```

Can anyone explain what the `subset` does and its relation with `is_best_movie`, as I am trying to find the lowest rated movies of all times and I am having issues with the year.

Comment: No. We can't. We need more of your code. Where subset variable comes from?

Comment: What do you mean *"issues with the year"*? Where did you get that code from, and what exactly don't you understand about what it does?

Comment: @DarthKotik: I don't see why the `subset` variable is an issue in this short code example. It is defined in the tuple unpacking step in the second line and simply contains the subset of the rows from `data`, for which the  value in the `year` column of `data` is equal to the local `year` variable defined in line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide very little data, making this a sort of a guessing game. However, I believe my guess is probable.

This line:

```
for year, subset in data.groupby('year'):
```

Suggests that `data` is a `DataFrame`, and from this line and the following it contains columns of `year`, `title`, and `rating`.

So, when you do `data.groupby('year')`, you get all the movies from the same year grouped together, and that's what `subset` contains.

```
is_best_movie = subset.rating == subset.rating.max()
```

This line turns `is_best_movie` into a boolean series, it's length equals to the length of `subset`, where all is False except for the movies with the maximal rating (there might be more than one who have the maximal rating). So when we do `subset[is_best_movie]` we get only the lines, from that year, which had the maximal rating.

```
best_movies.append([year,subset[is_best_movie].title.values[0], subset.rating.max()])
```

Here, the year, the first (it's kinda random) of the movies with the best ratings's title, and the best rating, are all added as a sublist to a list called `best_movies`.

And here:

```
best_df = pd.DataFrame(best_movies,columns=['year','title','rating'])
```

This list is turned again into a `DataFrame`.

So we had a DataFrame which I assume had lot's of movies, their year, and their rating, and we end up with a dataframe listing the "best" movie of each year.

If you want to find the lowest rated movies of all times, I guess you can just do:

```
data.sort('rating').iloc[:10]
```

This, for example, will get you the 10 movies with the worst rating.

Or, if as suggested in the comments, you want the worst movies *per year*, you need to change two lines:

```
is_best_movie = subset.rating == subset.rating.min()
best_movies.append([year,subset[is_best_movie].title.values[0], subset.rating.min()])
```

Comment: I like your answer. Unfortunately OP did not state their issue clearly. I think the `lowest rated movies of all times` refers to the `lowest rated movie for each year`. Which is a rather simple modification to the original code snippet once OP has figured out what all the defined variables contain.

Comment: Thank you @Korem. I am sorry for the trouble and the uncleared question but you got my answer. I thank you a lot!

Answer (score -1):

`is_best_movie` is a logical vector with `True`, if the rating of this movie is the maximum value, `False` otherwise.